ASP.NET Stripe Connect Embedded Payment - Fails to get session without Account Id
I'm working on providing embedded payment solutions for clients using Stripe Connect. I can successfully create a checkout session with the following server-side code:
                var options = new Stripe.Checkout.SessionCreateOptions
            {
                LineItems = new List<Stripe.Checkout.SessionLineItemOptions>
            {
                new Stripe.Checkout.SessionLineItemOptions
                {
                    PriceData = new Stripe.Checkout.SessionLineItemPriceDataOptions
                    {
                        Currency = "aud",
                        ProductData = new Stripe.Checkout.SessionLineItemPriceDataProductDataOptions
                        {
                            Name = "Gift Voucher",
                        },
                        UnitAmount = 30000,
                    },
                    Quantity = 1,
                },
            },
                PaymentIntentData = new Stripe.Checkout.SessionPaymentIntentDataOptions
                {
                    ApplicationFeeAmount = 110,
                },
                Mode = "payment",
                UiMode = "embedded",
                ReturnUrl = "https://localhost:44389/blah/StripeCheckoutReturn",
                ClientReferenceId = "12345"
            };
            var requestOptions = new RequestOptions
            {
                StripeAccount = "abcd..."
            };
            var service = new SessionService();
            Session session = service.Create(options, requestOptions);
            TempData["StripeSession"] = session.Id;
            return Json(new { clientSecret = session.ClientSecret });

The above code runs fine and I'm able to complete a test payment on the embedded Stripe payment form.
The problem occurs when I try to retrieve the session in my ReturnUrl endpoint. The code below fails with a Stripe exception saying no such checkout.session.
[HttpGet]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<ActionResult> StripeCheckoutReturn()
{
    string session_id = TempData["StripeSession"].ToString();
    var service = new SessionService();
    Session session = service.Get(session_id);
    if (session.PaymentStatus == "paid")
    {
    }
}

However, if I hard-code the Connect Client's account id, as follows, the error is gone and I successfully get the session.
[HttpGet]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<ActionResult> StripeCheckoutReturn()
{
    string session_id = TempData["StripeSession"].ToString();
    var requestOptions = new RequestOptions
    {
        StripeAccount = "acct_12345..."
    };
    var service = new SessionService();
    Session session = service.Get(session_id, requestOptions: requestOptions);
    if (session.PaymentStatus == "paid")
    {
    }
}

This results in a chicken and egg situation for me because as far as I can tell, I can't get the session without having the related client account no. But it's only after obtaining the session that I can get the "ClientReferenceId" which is what I need and use to reconcile the session with our internal systems.
I raised this issue with Stripe support and they initially came back to me saying that the problem was because I hadn't set the ApplicationFeeAmount. But when writing back my reply to their email support, stating that I had indeed set the amount properly and that the session resolves fine when I supply the client's account id, I simply got an automated email response advising me to contact Stripe using their chat, which is just a robot AI assistant.
I don't get a proper support ticket and there is no "Support" section on my Dashboard where I can manage support issues.

You should include a {CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID} in your return_url, for example: "https://localhost:44389/blah/StripeCheckoutReturn?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}". Upon completing a checkout session, Stripe will replace the {CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID} placeholder with the actual checkout sessions ID, so that your app can retrieve the Checkout Session ID from the query param. You can find example code here

Did you read my post? I'm aware I can include CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID. In testing I don't need to because I temporarily store it. The problem is not with the checkout session id, I can't get the session without also specifying the client's account id.

Then you should just include the account ID in the query param in the same way as {CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}. i.e., "https://localhost:44389/blah/StripeCheckoutReturn?account_id=abc&session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}"

I've read a lot of the Stripe API reference and there is nothing that says the return url supports any field or parameter other than {CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}. please point me to some reference that shows how to provide multiple values in the return url.

I just tested it out by adding multiple query parameters in the URL and it works for me. If you really want confirmation from Stripe then you should reach out to their support.

Stripe support is hit and miss. I logged this as a support issue but they replied saying the error was because I had not entered a value for the Application Fee. However, this is not the case. I wrote back explaining the exact problem, with examples of my code, and I simply got an automated response asking me to use chat. Multiple parameters would be great, but there is no documentation I can find on if/how the Connect Account ID can be sent as part of the return url. Also, in testing I can only use localhost.
